# Is load balancing supported?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

HTTP headers indicate that Firebase Hosting uses the popular nginx web server which is well known to often be deployed in a load balanced fashion. However, [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#choosing_an_option) indicates that load balancing is "n/a" or not applicable to Firebase Hosting.

Does Firebase Hosting support load balancing or not?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If it's a static website hosted on Firebase, the content is delivered by a CDN so "load balancing" doesn't really come into it. Hence the "n/a". Where load balancing comes in is with your cloud functions. Those are automatically load balanced.

Comment: So, if 100 users in the same geographic location navigate to a static webpage near simultaneously, there is no load balancing occurring on Google's nginx servers?

Comment: The CDN takes care of that. It will try to optimize delivery of the static content. There are many ways to do that, but that's not "load balancing". It may replicate the content at multiple endpoints, deliver it out of RAM vs. off disk, etc.

Comment: The CDN __is__ Firebase Hosting. HTTP load balancing == load balancing. Granted, Firebase Hosting's CDN is actually Fastly but that's besides the point.

Comment: I think their intent is that the CDN is covered under the "scalability=Automatically" column in that chart rather than the "load balancing" column. But as you point out, it could be clearer if it said "automatic" under load balancing there.

Comment: Suppose I'm using firebase as backend service for my mobile application. Does it scale automatically when more users come ?